# How to create .rdlc files?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2010 for generating reports using report viewer... As I am totally new to this, I don't know how to create an RDLC file and how to use it... Also, please tell me that what the connection is between Report Viewer and rdlc

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Possibly relevant, but if you do happen to be hosting on Azure Websites, just know you'll face some issues with using RDLC reports due to some security restrictions. Azure Web Roles are fine. Long shot but may save you some headaches if you're going that route. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add an RDLC report do `Project > Add New Item... > Reporting > Report`. You can also use the Report Wizard which is on the same screen. RDLC has a large wealth of information you will need to know about, so you will want to [start digging into the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**Creating Client Report Definition (.rdlc) Files**

Here is the answer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx

To add a new report to a project

1. In the Project or Web Site menu, select Add New Item.
2. In the Add New Item dialog box, in the Installed Templates pane, select Visual Basic or Visual C#.
3. In the Templates pane, select Report or Report Wizard.

If you select Report, a blank .rdlc file is added to the project. For more information on how to design reports in Report Designer, see Reporting Services Reports in SQL Server Books Online.
If you select Report Wizard, the Report Wizard is started to guide you through the steps in creating a report. For more information on the Report Wizard, see Creating Client Report Definitions Using the Visual Studio Report Wizard.